# Differentiability of PDE with respect to parameters

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider a linear partial differential equation

$$
(L u)(x)=f(x) \quad \forall x \text{ in } \Omega\\
u=g \quad\text{on }\partial\Omega.
$$
Assuming that $f$ and $L$ depend on a parameter $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $f=f(x,y)$, $L=\sum_{\alpha} a_\alpha(x,y)\partial^\alpha$ how is the regularity of $u$ with respect to $y$ related to $L$? Just by differentiating formally, I would guess that $u$ is approximately as regular w.r.t. $y$ as $f$ is, whenever there is some sort of regularity result for $L(y)$, because
$$
(L \frac{d}{dy} u)(x)=\frac{d}{dy}f(x,y)-\sum_{\alpha}\frac{d}{dy} a(x,y)\partial^{\alpha} u(x)
$$
In particular, I expect infinite differentiability w.r.t. $y$ of $f$ and $L$ imply the same for $u$ at points where there are regularity results for $L(y)$ in a neighborhood of $y$.

If what I guess is wrong, can you hint at the problems with my arguments/their rigorousification?

Comment: I'm not sure what the second equation means. (Are there typos? Zero on the left-hand side maybe?) Anyway, I suspect that smoothness of $a_{\alpha}$ with respect to $y$ might not be enough. I believe zeros of some $a_{\alpha}$ might cause irregularity, but I could be wrong.

Comment: There was a typo indeed, which is now fixed. The second equation is supposed to show that $\frac{d}{dy}u(x,y)$ satisfies the same PDE (with respect to $x$), only with a different RHS, and thus should exist by some limiting/regularity argument. To your second point: I hoped zeros of $a_\alpha$ are covered by requiring regularity results (e.g. ellipticity) of $L(y)$ in a neighborhood around $y$

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean now. In that case, I tend to believe the answer is positive. You have the same differential operator acting on $u$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ (and all its higher $y$ derivatives), and the non-homogeneous term seems to possess the same type of regularity.

Comment: I am interested in this question. Did you get an answer after 6 years? Thanks in advance